# generating random number excluding some numbers

Tags: python

first of all, i know there are solutions to this problem on the internet already, but I can't understand them, because it's my first project and i've only started to learn programming 3 days ago. I would really appreciate somebody helping me and explaining the solution to this specific program i'm trying to write.
The concept is pretty easy, i'm trying to make a password generator which randomly generates a password using 2 upper case letters, 2 lower case letters, 2 digits and 2 punctuation marks.

My problem is : I'm trying to use python to generate a number and then i associate the number with the ASCii so i have a punctuation marks, the problem is that when i generate the number from a range, some of the punctuation marks have different ranges and instead of having punctuation mark sometimes i have a letter or a number. I would like to use a loop for it so the program's keep generating a number until it's different from the "excluded numbers".

so here's the code i wrote, don't laugh at me, it's my third day in programming and i realised that by doing projects i'm learning much more and having much more fun.

```
import random
import string

do_they_want_the_pass = input("Would you like to create a random password? /n Type 'yes' or 'no' ")
if do_they_want_the_pass == "yes":
    print("Okay, let's go then, just give me 3 miliseconds")
    

upper_case_letter1 = chr(random.randint(65,90))
upper_case_letter2 = chr(random.randint(65,90))
lower_case_letter1 = chr(random.randint(97,122))
lower_case_letter2 = chr(random.randint(97,122))
digit1 = random.randint(0, 9)
digit2 = random.randint(0, 9)
exclude_set1 = list(range(48,57))
exclude_set2 = list(range(65,90))
exclude_set3 = list(range(97,122))
exclude_set4 = list(range(127,144))
exclude_set5 = list(range(150,151))
all_exlcluded = (exclude_set1 + exclude_set2 + exclude_set3 + exclude_set4 + exclude_set5)
punc1 = chr(random.randint(33,152))
punc2 = chr(random.randint(33,152))
password = upper_case_letter1 + upper_case_letter2 + lower_case_letter1 + lower_case_letter2 + str(digit1) + str(digit2) + str(punc1) + str(punc2)
print(password)
```

`
as i specified above ;)

Comment: Rather than dealing with character codes at all, just pick a random character from a collection of allowed punctuation marks - `random.choice("!@#$%^&*()")` for example.

Comment: Do you mean `\n` instead of `/n`?

Comment: _instead of having punctuation mark sometimes i have a letter or a number_ So... use a range that **only** includes actual punctuation marks?  I don't understand the difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I will try to modify your answer while keeping it as close as possible to how you wrote (just so you can understand), then, I will show you a much better way of doing it, using the `string` library, which you imported, but never used, as well as using `random.choices` (or `random.sample`) instead of `random.randint`.

1. Continuing your way:

First, you're not using `all_excluded` at all, and second, you don't need to use `str` on the punctuation characters, they're already string-type. Also, unlike `random.randint`, `range` excludes the end value, and, punctuation codes stop at `126` (inclusive). So overall I would just do the following modifications:

```
# starting code unmodified

exclude_set1 = list(range(48, 58)) # add 1 to all end values of the ranges
exclude_set2 = list(range(65, 91))
exclude_set3 = list(range(97, 123)) # don't need exclude_set4 and exclude_set5
all_excluded = exclude_set1 + exclude_set2 + exclude_set3
punct_values = set(range(33, 127)).difference(all_excluded)

### Alternatively (better), you can build the punct_values from punctuation ranges
### instead of building the big range and excluding non-punctuation ranges
### Second approach:

punct_range_1 = list(range(33, 48))
punct_range_2 = list(range(58, 65))
punct_range_3 = list(range(91, 97))
punct_range_4 = list(range(123, 127))
punct_values = punct_range_1 + punct_range_2 + punct_range_3 + punct_range_4

# after either approach:

punc1 = chr(random.choice(punct_values))
punc2 = chr(random.choice(punct_values))

password = upper_case_letter1 + upper_case_letter2 + lower_case_letter1 + lower_case_letter2 + str(digit1) + str(digit2) + punc1 + punc2

# rest of code unmodified
```

2. Using `string` and `random.choices` (or `random.sample`):

The difference between using `random.choices` and `random.sample` is that the former does sampling with replacement, while the latter does sampling without replacement, i.e., `random.choices` could produce duplicates, while `random.sample` returns unique elements, otherwise, their usage is the same:

```
import string
import random

#     or random.sample (string.ascii_lowercase, k=2) if you don't want duplicates, same goes for other calls
lowers = random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=2)
uppers = random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=2)
digits = random.choices(string.digits, k=2)
puncts = random.choices(string.punctuation, k=2)

password = ''.join(lowers + uppers + digits + puncts)

### string.join(sequence) is similar to:
### sequence[0] + string + sequence[1] + string + ... + string + sequence[len(sequence) - 1]
### when using it with an empty string, it's similar to simply adding the strings
### in the sequence together with no separator
### as in sequence[0] + sequence[1] + ... + sequence[len(sequence) - 1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've marked this comment as the one that solved my problem, just because I could understand it the most. Thanks for explaining it to me in a way I could grasp it. Hopefully in a few years I will be able to give back to the community by helping some newbie, like you helped me. Thanks again and take care ! <3

Comment: @JakubMazurek Glad to have helped! Looking forward for your contributions :).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, it's just easier and more legible to use `random.choice` to select a random character from a given sequence. The string module also already has strings defined with all letters, digits, etc. that you can use.

```
import string
import random

upper_case_letter1 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
upper_case_letter2 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
lower_case_letter1 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
lower_case_letter2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
digit1 = random.choice(string.digits)
digit2 = random.choice(string.digits)
punc1 = random.choice(string.punctuation)
punc2 = random.choice(string.punctuation)
password = upper_case_letter1 + upper_case_letter2 + lower_case_letter1 + lower_case_letter2 + digit1 + digit2 + punc1 + punc2
print(password)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The string module is very interesting and I'll definitely look into it. I learn a lot from every comment and I've just learned a lot from yours. Thank you very much and hopefully I'll be able to pass this knowledge to another newbie like me in some time( when i get more advanced) much appreciated, take care :D

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing your code, I would probably also go with the suggested good comment of using a random choice function call.  Viewing the code, creating an exclusion list appeared to mean you were looking to acquire an integer value and then determine if it should be excluded for the punctuation marks.  However, that list was not being used in your current version.

If you are adamant in generating punctuation mark characters via an exclusion method, following is a refactored version of your code utilizing a function to perform that task.

```
import random
import string

def Special_Char():
    while True:
        test = random.randint(33,152)   # A simple "brute force" while loop function that keeps generating a random value until it is a punctuation, and then returns the character value
        if ((test < 48) or (test > 57 and test < 65) or (test > 90 and test < 97) or (test > 122 and test < 127) or (test > 144 and test < 150) or test > 151):
            return chr(test)

do_they_want_the_pass = input("Would you like to create a random password? /n Type 'yes' or 'no' ")
if do_they_want_the_pass == "yes":
    print("Okay, let's go then, just give me 3 miliseconds")

    upper_case_letter1 = chr(random.randint(65,90))
    upper_case_letter2 = chr(random.randint(65,90))
    lower_case_letter1 = chr(random.randint(97,122))
    lower_case_letter2 = chr(random.randint(97,122))
    digit1 = str(random.randint(0, 9))                  # Just making the value into a string/character here so that all that is subsequently done is concatenation
    digit2 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
    punc1 = Special_Char()
    punc2 = Special_Char()

    password = upper_case_letter1 + upper_case_letter2 + lower_case_letter1 + lower_case_letter2 + digit1 + digit2 + punc1 + punc2

    print(password)

else:
    print("Okay - no password will be generated")
```

The bits to point out are as follows:

- The generation of punctuation mark characters is performed via a function call which performs the exclusion method you intimate.
- Any conversion to characters or string values are performed as part of the character assignment so as to simplify the password generation as simple character concatenation.
- An "else" clause was added just to complete the logic process of the program.

Definitely note that there are multiple for random character generation.  This is just one way that attempts to stay close to the coding style you are using.

Testing out this refactored code yielded the following terminal test output.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Passwords$ python3 Random.py 
Would you like to create a random password? /n Type 'yes' or 'no' no
Okay - no password will be generated
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Passwords$ python3 Random.py 
Would you like to create a random password? /n Type 'yes' or 'no' yes
Okay, let's go then, just give me 3 miliseconds
MJww28)@
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Passwords$ python3 Random.py 
Would you like to create a random password? /n Type 'yes' or 'no' yes
Okay, let's go then, just give me 3 miliseconds
LVxz60*#
```

Go ahead and dissect this refactored code to get an understanding.  And since you note that you are just getting your feet wet, definitely seek out some good tutorials on this language, either online or literature.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, also thank you very much for directing me in my future path. I'll definitely get my hands on some good literature and online tutorials. Do you have any books for beginners in mind? 
I really like the 'brute force ' idea , I don't fully understand it, but I just saved your comment and going to study it a bit more to fully grasp everything you've showed me .
Thank you very much again and I'll make sure that some day in future I'll be able to help some newbie just like you helped me. Take care ;)

Comment: I do not have any specific books in mind.  You might just want to perform a web search for "Python tutorial book" and view what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You could generalize this using a dictionary for the character categories.  Your password would then be defined by a pattern string referring to categories:

```
import string
import random

categ = { "A": string.ascii_uppercase, # "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
          "a": string.ascii_lowercase, # "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
          "0": string.digits,          # "0123456789"
          ".": string.punctuation }    # '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

password = "".join(random.choice(categ[c]) for c in "aaAA00..")

print(password) # bjOB02?\
```

You can use any list of characters for your categories and define more of them easily.  Each category only contains the characters you're interested in so you don't have to write a trial-and-error loop to exclude undesirable characters.

This would also allow you to randomize the order:

```
rndPattern = random.sample("aaAA00..",8)
password   = "".join(random.choice(categ[c]) for c in rndPattern)

print(password) # ~cE9K1'f
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, even though it's gonna take me some time to study it to understand it fully.  I am very grateful and I'm gonna study your answer and learn as much as I can from it. Also thank you so much for randomizing the password, that was my next planned step , I am gonna try to do it your way now. Thanks for helping me and I hope I'll be able to help somebody else one day. Take care ;)